# Can't install libnuma-dev on raspbian

Tags: raspbian

```
sudo apt-get install libnuma-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libnuma-dev
```

This is problem what I have.
I tried `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` already.

Here is my source.list

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ stretch main contrib non-free rpi 
#Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
#deb-src http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ stretch main contrib non-free rpi
```

My device is 'raspberry pi 3 B+' and OS is raspbian9.

Answer (score 0):

My device is raspberry pi CM3 lite and OS is raspbian 9 too. I encountered this problem when I want to compile the [rt-tests](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/realtime/documentation/howto/tools/rt-tests) tools from source code. But I successfully compiled the tools without install "libnuma-dev" library. Hope it helps for you and any other one who maybe want to compile the rt-tests tools acoording to the official wiki.